# AWS S3 policy with more than action and effect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need a policy for a bucket on AWS to have more than one action and effect. I want to allow the bucket to be able to get, but I want to prevent anyone from being able to delete it
I created it like this:

```json
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[
       {
          "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": "s3:GetObject",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::alex.santos-denydelete/*",
          "Principal": "*"
       },
       {
          "Effect": "Deny",
          "Action": "s3:DeleteBucket",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::alex.santos-denydelete/*",
          "Principal": "*"
       }
    ]
 }
```

But when saving I get the error:

> Unknown Error
> An unexpected error occurred.
> API response
> Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s3:DeleteBucket` action requires a bucket resource, so you need to remove the  `/*` at the end of the resource string.